# Example of a ring with zero dimension that is not Artinian (Atiyah - MacDonald)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and consider the ring $A=K[x_1,x_2,\cdots]$ in countably infinite indeterminates and its ideal $\alpha=(x_1,x_2^2,\cdots,x_n^n,\cdots)$. Then Atiya and
MacDonald in their "Introduction to Commutative Algebra", top of page 91, mention that the only prime ideal
of $A/ \alpha$ is the image of $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. I can see that the image of this ideal is
prime, however how can we see that it is the only prime?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the relation between the primes of $B$ and the primes of $B/\mathcal{N}(B)$ where $\mathcal{N}(B)$ is the nilradical?

Comment: Manos, are you the one with the Hands of Fate?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry, i don't see what you mean...

Comment: @Matt: In your notation, the image of every prime ideal of $B$ is a prime ideal of $B/\mathcal{N}(B)$ and conversely...

Comment: Isn't the example $\alpha=(x_1^2,x_2^2,\dots)$ easier?

Comment: @Manos: Luckily, Google knows what I'm talking about... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Hahahaha, i see now...Good for me, i have nothing to do with this film :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt mentions in the comments:

Let $B=A/\alpha$ as in the question. If $x \in B$ satisfies $x^n = 0$ and $P$ is a prime ideal, then since $o \in P$, either $x$ or $x^{n-1}$ in $P$. By induction, $x \in P$. In particular each $x_i + \alpha \in B$ is contained in each prime ideal $P$.  Hence the image $P$ of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is the unique minimal prime ideal. The quotient ring is isomorphic to the field $K$, so $P$ is also a maximal ideal. Hence it is the only prime ideal of $B$.  $B$ is not artinian, since it contains the descending chain of ideals $P_i = (x_i, x_{i+1}, \ldots) \leq P$.